# Import CSV file in PostgreSQL table (duplicate rows)

Tags: sql, postgresql

i need to finish my query to add rows that not exists in table `testcsv2` from the temporary table `tmp_x`:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x AS SELECT * FROM testcsv2 LIMIT 0;

COPY tmp_x FROM 'D:\water_utility2.csv' (FORMAT csv);

UPDATE testcsv2
SET    record = tmp_x.record, "Battery Voltage" = tmp_x."Battery Voltage"
FROM   tmp_x
WHERE  testcsv2.timestamp = tmp_x.timestamp;

DROP TABLE tmp_x;
```

Can you help me, please?

Update:

```
TABLE testcsv2 
(TIMESTAMP timestamp, RECORD double precision, "Battery Voltage" double precision);
```

Table `tmp_x` is with the same columns. Filled with thata from csv:

```
2009-12-31 23:00:00,112086,13.56197
2009-12-31 23:15:00,102087,23.56113
2009-12-31 23:30:00,102088,13.56449
2010-01-01 23:45:00,102089,13.57373
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
insert into testcsv2 select * from (
select x.* 
from tmp_x x
left outer join testcsv2 t on t. timestamp = x. timestamp
where t. timestamp is null
) as missing;
```

Comment: Error code 0, SQL state 42601: ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Comment: you have to map columns. please update the OP with tables structure if you want me to do it

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: oh, my bad - forgot to select from tmp_x only - updated the answer

Comment: Its working, thank you very much! But what 'x' and 't' does?

Comment: my pleasure. those are aliases - short names

Comment: One more thing. How to not include csv header if exist in the CSV file for this query?

Comment: just `with (header, format csv)` - it will skip header on load